# C++ Pointers Confusion

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, variable-assignment

While defining a pointer variable, we use code that looks like

```
int *ip;
```

but we can also initialize the pointer in the same line to point a random defined variable say x.

```
int x;
int *ip = &x;
```

and we can also initialize the pointer variable in another line of code for example,

```
int x;
int *ip;
ip = &x;
```

My question is that when I use `*ip` to initialize the pointer variable,

```
int x;
int *ip;
*ip = &x;
```

Visual Studio gives an error:

> Error C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int'

Can Someone please explain it to me, I have just started learning C++.

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: The lines of code that you have posted work but you forgot to post the line(s) of code that doesn't(don't) work. That is not helpful to anybody that wants to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please notice the data types there.

When you write

```
ip = &x;
```

this is an [assignment statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)). You're trying to store the address of `x` (a pointer, basically `int *`) into `ip`, which is also a variable of type pointer to `int` (again, `int *`). All good.

On the other hand, when you try to write

```
*ip = &x;
```

This is also an assignment, but here, `*ip` is an `int` type and `&x` is `int *` and they are not compatible. Hence your compiler warns you for good.

---

FWIW,

```
 int *ip = &x;
```

is fine, because this is [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)), not only a simple assigment. You are initializing variable `ip` (of type `int *`) at the time of definition. Remember, the variable getting defined and initialized here is `ip`, not `*ip` and this is very different from writing

```
*ip = &x;
```

(*which as I already mentioned, is improper.*)

Comment: @JesperJuhl or your keyboard? :)

Comment: fastest finger _(thinker)_ first :)

Answer (score 0):

**Be careful**: There is a difference between:

- `ip = &x;` Here you allocate the pointer `ip` with the address of `x`
- and `*ip = x;` Here you set the value where `ip` points to, with the value of `x`

Attention: `*ip = &x;` is a mix of both and therefore won't work

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is only from the syntax of the pointer at the declaration line.

when you declare a Pointer, you write `int *p`, which means `define symbol **p** to be of type Pointer to **int**` and the Assign `=` is providing value to `p` and not `*p`.

when not on the declaration line, there is no confusion! `p` is the Pointer. and `*p` is the value.

Other way to say it... if declaring a pointer was done by `ptr2int p = &i`, i guess it was clearer.

that is the reason why many people rather declare pointer types as `int* p` instead of the `int *p`. small semantics that makes people happy :)

Cheers.